# Can an amplifier deliver a higher power for a short burst as opposed to continuously using the same circuit

Tags: power, current, amplifier

I am struggling to understand the fundamental power requirements for an amplifier.

If I want to deliver 56 V rms to a 7.5 Ohm load I can use P = V^2/R and find that I need 418 W rms. Requiring a current of 7.5 A rms.

But this is for transmission in a continuous mode. If, for example I only want the amplifier to transmit 10% of the time, for example, for only 100 mS in 1 S, sitting idle the rest of the time. Does my power requirement change?

And how is this change manifested?

Does the current requirement drop (meaning I need less output transistors in parallel)?

Comment: There is no such thing as "418 W RMS".  It's just watts.  RMS makes no sense in this context.

Comment: Sorry, I meant RMS as opposed to peak, This isn't my area of expertise. I have seen many amplifier companies who quote values of X watts RMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The average power reduces as you lower the duty cycle and this usually means less heating in the power transistors and power supply to the amplifier. So, if full duty consumes 418 watts, 10% duty consumes 41.8 watts in the load.

The current will still be 7.5 amps when driving the load and will be zero amps when not driving the load. The RMS current can be calculated by the average power of 41.8 watts into 7.5 ohms thus, RMS current is

\$\sqrt{\dfrac{41.8}{7.5}}\$ = 2.36 amps.

Note that the average current may also be a useful quantity.

More than likely you will be able to use fewer transistors in the output stage.

Comment: Ok thanks Andy, This is the problem I have trouble understanding, I can appreciate that the average current will drop, but, because during transmission I still require 7.5 Amps. Why am I able to use fewer transistors? I'm my application the duty will be much lower, more like 0.01%. I was using 10% as a simple value to understand the concept.

Comment: Usually the number of banked transistors on a power amp relates to the average power delivered and hence to the RMS current delivered so if you have 7.5 amps (RMS) continuous and 2.36 amps (RMS) at 10% then usually the power loss in the transistor bank is proportional to RMS hence, on a good day you should be able to reduce transistors by 7.5:2.36 = about 3:1 (not 10:1 as implied by the average).

Comment: Whilst I (think) I have understood what you have said, I still have the same issue. If I (for example) use 15 500mA transistors to provide 7.5 A of current, when I reduce this to 5, using the ratio you provided, why wont they melt when they are required to provide 7.5 A? Even if it is only for a short amount of time...

Comment: I'm talking about transistor power ratings (basically heat) based on RMS currents through the devices. Of course the absolute current limit for each transistor has to be steered clear of.